# Scheduled Task wont open my Jar

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I am currently trying to create a scheduled task, that runs my Jar file every minute. the command line code to create the task looks like this:

`schtasks /Create /tn Testname /sc Minute /tr C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Program.jar`

no matter how long I wait, nothing happens. The Scheduled Task GUI shows that the result of my task is `(0x1)`

Howwever if I run `C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Program.jar` in the CMD everything works fine

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The command that you want to run is `java -jar <path_to_your_jar_file>` The jar file itself is not an executable task. By the way if the frequency of execution is every minute then I won't do it by OS scheduler, I would rather use some kind of in app time service.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution @BalázsNemes by doing this: `schtasks /Create /tn Testname /sc Minute /tr \"java -jar C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Program.jar"` but now it tells me that -jar is an invalid option/arguement, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the syntax of the schtasks command. But, you can create a .bat file and add the command that I wrote into it. Then in the schtasks you can use this bat file as your task. Also it may need to reference the java executable with full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create the scheduled task via Java, I dont know if this will help somebody in the future, but just in case I am gonna post my code anyway:

```
private void createScheduledTask(String taskName) {
    List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<String>();
    commandList.add("schtasks.exe");
    commandList.add("/Create");
    commandList.add("/tn");
    commandList.add(taskName);
    commandList.add("/sc");
    commandList.add("Minute");
    commandList.add("/tr");
    commandList.add("java -jar C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\Program.jar REPLACE_WITH_ARGUMENT");
    try {
        int returnValue = executeCMDStatement(commandList);
        if(returnValue == 0){
            //everything should have worked out
        } else {
            //there was an error 
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static int executeCMDStatement(List<String> commandList) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
    Process process = builder.start();
    process.waitFor(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return process.exitValue();
}
```